# Can someone explain this expression: a[len(a):] = [x] equivalent to list.append(x)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm at the very beginning of learning Python 3. Getting to know the language basics. There is a method to the list data type:

```
list.append(x)
```

and in the tutorial it is said to be equivalent to this expression:

```
a[len(a):] = [x]
```

Can someone please explain this expression? I can't grasp the **len(a):** part. It's a slice right? From the last item to the last? Can't make sense of it.

I'm aware this is very newbie, sorry. I'm determined to learn Python for Blender scripting and the Game Engine, and want to understand well all the constructs.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense.  Are you sure it isn't `a.append(x)`

Comment: In some sense `a.append(x)` is equivalent to the unPythonic `a[len(a):] = [x]` (the net result is to mutate `a` the same way). But in another sense they aren't equivalent in that they correspond to very different byte code. The latter is almost certainly much less efficient than the former.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Think back to how slices work: `a[beginning:end]`.
If you do not supply one of them, then you get all the list from `beginning` or all the way to `end`.

What that means is if I ask for `a[2:]`, I will get the list from the index `2` all the way to the end of the list and `len(a)` is an index right after the last element of the array... so `a[len(a):]` is basically an empty array positioned right after the last element of the array.

Say you have `a = [0,1,2]`, and you do `a[3:] = [3,4,5]`, what you're telling Python is that right after `[0,1,2` and right before `]`, there should be `3,4,5`.
Thus `a` will become `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and after that step `a[3:]` will indeed be equal to `[3,4,5]` just as you declared.

Edit: as chepner commented, any index greater than or equal to `len(a)` will work just as well. For instance, `a = [0,1,2]` and `a[42:] = [3,4,5]` will also result in `a` becoming `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly that bounds checking doesn't apply to slices; `a[x:] == []` for *all* `x >= len(a)`.

Answer (score 7):

One could generally state that `l[len(l):] = [1]` is similar to `append`, *[and that is what is stated in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)*, but, that is a *special case* that holds true only when the right hand side *has a single element*.

In the more *general case* it is safer to state that it is equivalent to `extend` for the following reasons:

Append takes an *object* and appends that to the end; with slice assignment you **extend** a list with the given iterable on the right hand side:

```
l[len(l):] = [1, 2, 3]
```

is equivalent to:

```
l.extend([1, 2, 3])
```

The same argument to `append` would cause `[1, 2, 3]` to be appended as  an object at the end of `l`. In this scenario `len(l)` is simply used in order for the extending of the list to be performed at the end of `l`.

Some examples to illustrate their difference:

```
l = [1, 2]
l[len(l):] = [1, 2]   # l becomes [1, 2, 1, 2]
l.extend([1, 2])      # l becomes [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
l.append([1, 2])      # l becomes [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, [1, 2]]
```

As you note, `l.append(<iterable>)` doesn't actually append each value in the iterable, it appends the iterable itself.